# Javascript - How do I get a statement to work once, not work if it did it 1 time already, then work again?

Tags: javascript, loops, expression, repeat

I know the title may be a bit confusing so allow me to explain my situation.

Basically I made a dragon mini-game and one of the features is a talk function which allows the console to randomize a message after striking the dragon. Now however, I want to add a 2nd feature that allows that talk function to exist and activate, but in the case that its already activated in the previous turn, I want it to not work and use a different talk message.

So instead of saying something like:

I striked the dragon! 
I striked the dragon! 
I striked the dragon! 
I hit the dragon!

I want it to always randomize each time and not repeat itself.

I striked the dragon! 
I hit the dragon!
I striked the dragon!
I hit the dragon!

The code i'm using is way to long so i'll give you a snipet of what I can.

```
 player.TALK = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
if (player.HP >= 1) {
if ((player.DAMAGE >= 1) && (player.AIM >= 3) && (player.SPECIALAIM >= 2)){
    npc.HP = npc.HP - player.DAMAGE;
    if (player.TALK === 0) {console.log("PLAYER HP: " + player.HP + " --You hammer the Dragon for " + player.DAMAGE + " hp! " + "It only has " + npc.HP + "hp left!--");
    }
    if (player.TALK === 1) {console.log("PLAYER HP: " + player.HP + " --You slice the Dragon for " + player.DAMAGE + " hp! " + "It only has " + npc.HP + "hp left!--");
    }
    if (player.TALK === 2) {console.log("PLAYER HP: " + player.HP + " --You sever the Dragon for " + player.DAMAGE + " hp! " + "It only has " + npc.HP + "hp left!--");
    }
```

This is a small piece of the larger code I have which would be way too much to post here.

Basically what i'm trying to figure out is how to get the computer to execute a statement once, and when it loops back around to it again, if its ALREADY used it last time, to not use it again, but not completely break it where it NEVER uses it again, just if it used it last time, then it won't repeat, and use a different talk option instead.

Comment: Just keep track of the index of the last thing you said, and pick another one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an auxiliary array with gets emptied from time to time, and refilled then. Leaving hp and stuff aside, it's something like:

```
player.TALK=['you pwn the dragon','you kick the dragon','you eviscerate the dragon'];
player.AUXTALK=player.TALK.slice(0);

function killdragon(player) {
    var talkindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * player.AUXTALK.length);
    console.log(player.AUXTALK[talkindex]);
    delete player.AUXTALK[talkindex];
    if (player.AUXTALK.length==0) player.AUXTALK=player.TALK.slice(0);
}
```